# PHP CURL: HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required

Tags: php, curl, content-length

Even I have specified the Content Length, I still receive the error:

> ### Length Required
>
> ---
>
> HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.

This is my code

```
$curl = curl_init();
$data = array("Key" => "Value", "Key2" => "Value2");
$data = json_encode($data);
$length = strlen($data);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8", "Content-Length: $length"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you need to be using the NTLM authentication option?

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);`

I tested with this and it causes the `content-type` header as well as the JSON payload to be omitted from the request.

Try removing that line and see the request works.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. The application is protected by a Windows authentication.

Comment: In my test the `CURLAUTH_NTLM` option in conjunction with `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` and a content-length header caused neither the content-length or the POST data to be sent.  I was of course not testing with a server expecting NTLM so that may have caused the problem.  Since NTLM is based on negotiation, you may need to issue one request with curl to auth, and then a subsequent PUT request to the API.  Is their public documentation for the API you're working with?

Comment: Unfortunately no public API, but issueing two request, the first just to authenticate, did the job!

Answer (score 2):

You set Content-length to the length of $data, but you post $update_json instead $data

Comment: Copy/Paste error. Sorry. Thats couldn't fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

I had, sort of, the same problem and was breaking my brains on it for a couple of hours.
Just remove the content-length from the header:

like this

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8"))
```

Comment: I was using php-curl-class using  NLTM authentication and it was omitting my header"Content-Length". I spent my whole day trying to figure it out. It worked without any issue for the POST but for the PUT request, I had to set  header "content-type" like it said to make it work. Not sure why its working for POST and not for PUT request though. Thank you.